# git push origin master:refs/heads/master what does this do

Tags: git, gitolite

When I create a new repo on my gitolite repository I always have to enter the following command before I can start pushing code to the server.

`git push origin master:refs/heads/master`

What does it do ?

My guess is that is has to do with the head reference not sure. Could someone explain it to me?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There's three parts to this command:

```
git push
```

This invokes the push command

```
origin
```

This names the remote to which you are pushing. This is either one of the named remotes stored in .git/config (you can list these with `git remote`), a URL, or the token `.` which means the current repository.

```
master:refs/heads/master
```

This is called a "refspec", and you can read about it in the man page for `git push`. But in general, it's comprised of two parts, separated by a colon. The first part is the name of a local branch, and the second part is the name of a branch on the remote repository (in this case, `origin`). This particular refspec could be shortened to `master:master`.

In general, one can shorten refspecs even further. Just specifying `master` as the refspec is equivalent to using the same name on the remote, so `master` is the same as `master:master`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. I just want to add a link to the git documentation on Refspec here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec
And also add that this is a useful tool for pushing a different branch, namespace, or even repo onto a remote's branch. I have found this useful for automating the process of pushing static assets to gh-pages after compiling with Jekyll to support plugins there.

Answer (score 5):

`master:refs/heads/master` is a refspec.

`refspecs` are of the form `+<src>:<dst>`

So here master is the ref on your local repo that you are pushing to the `refs/heads/master` refspec on the remote (origin). `master` is short for `refs/heads/master` actually.

In fact, you can just do `git push origin master` whereby it will push master on your local to master on remote. Only when you want to push to a different ref do you need to explicitly specify the destination ref.

Also just  `git push` has default behaviour too, which probably wouldn't have been the case before you did the first push and created a branch (master ) on the remote. So it would have seemed like you need to do the command you had mentioned. Refer to the manual

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior of `git push`, which is presumably what you describe as "pushing code to the server", is to only push local branches that have a matching branch, by name, on the remote you're pushing to. When you create a new repo, it has no branches in it, so a simple `git push` will push nothing. You have to explicitly push a branch by name first. Thereafter, the default behavior will work as you expect it to.

P.S. Actually, you only have to `git push origin master`. What it does is push your local master to the gitolite repo as master, since you didn't specify a different name. If you said `git push origin master:foo`, then the branch you locally call "master" would be known as "foo" on gitolite.

P.P.S. You can switch default push behavior between "nothing", "matching" (the default), "trackings"/"upstream", and "current". See the settings for "push.default" on the [git-config man page](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.2.5/git-config.html).

Answer (score 1):

It sets up tracking for you. You can use the shorthand for this:

```
git push origin master
```

The part after the colon is the name of the branch on the remote repo. If you omit it, git assumes you want the same name.

Hope this helps.