# ubuntu server with gitolite password

Tags: git, ubuntu, passwords, gitolite

I am trying to setup gitolite on Ubuntu Server! It seems to work as I could clone gitolite-admin

But when I try to issue the command on the client

```
git clone gitolite@ubuntu-server:testing
```

It ask for a password for gitolite, but my ssh password that I configured on the client is not accepted

Have I done anything wrong somewhere?

I did copy the .pub to the server and ran gl-setup without problems

NB: I am very green with git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the content, on the server gitolite account, of:

```
 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You should see your public key within a gitolite start / gitolite-end:

```
#more authorized_keys
# gitolite start
command="/home/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell gitoliteadm",no-port-forwarding,no-X11-forwarding,no-agent-forwarding,no-pty ssh-rsa ABCAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCxy5Y1epgjph3h439etAognIP4rlpDlD0OBh2rh+9DHMwlMad04zb3Tah5HQ
10Zg7mFWvltZlIBdhk5cBr3/mN1dNiRFspKwD2Z0yQaaI23zjHnXRAgLV76SOImICUt9CfCtGOy6jQH+2x4j921DL2cT8Ib+RslhBUEUdc3qNvOQSNhIz2qTVHJ676ohGFiqitgswIVIk6WRS+fERx6JFy9o7rLnnOCrozHYU271TwFgYqfNS7TuV4ZFwTP04hDGN+YALjvcQ0KGQGY/7qok+h5nHoRh9RDTeSJ2gDK2M4QPrTCzkCa0ebCexP2lR9G0iXYcClzXitttKDH7cls0j Gitolite Admin access (not interactive)
# gitolite end
```

Make sure to use the latest gitolite (V3), which is the case if you have:

```
/path/to/gitolite/bin/gitolite-shell
```

(you can execute: `gitolite-shell xxx` on the server to check what version you are using)

Make also sure to *not* protect (at least at first) your private ssh key with a password.

If it keeps asking you for a password, edit your question with the content of:

```
ssh -vvv gitolite@ubuntu-server
```

---

The OP adds:

> If I run `git clone morten@ubuntu-server:testing` and type my password everything works well... But now I can't seem to push anything to the repository

That means now the ssh part is running properly, however don't forget your first push must be a:

```
git push origin master
```

(see "[git push origin master:refs/heads/master what does this do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7506906/6309)")

That is because the default push policy (which [might change soon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749477/6309)) is to push *matching* branches (and if you didn't push anything yet, there wouldn't be a `master` branch on the remote repo yet)

The other trick is to make sure you are on a branch before pushing

```
git checkout master
git push
```

(and not trying to push while you are in a [detached head mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714))

Comment: If I run git clone morten@ubuntu-server:testing and type my password everything works well... 

But now I can't seem to push anything to the repository

Comment: Nevermind .. forgot to set master! :)

It seems to work as it should for what I want to use it for! :)
Thanks for the answer

Comment: @MortenHagh: good! Did you change anything in order for the `git clone` to work?

Comment: Thanks for this great answer! :-) I did not change anything besides the user on the ssh. Gitweb also seems to work! Adding a new project/repository seems a bit hard as I ssh onto the server and mkdir a new folder in /repositories/ and then git init etc. but might just be easier when I get used to it.

Comment: @MortenHagh just to be sure: you don't ssh in order to add/create new repos with gitolite. You declare a new repo in the local clone of the `gitolite-admin` repo, and you push that repo. Gitolite will parse its `gitolite.conf` file and create the new repos appropriately. See http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/repos.html

Comment: Arh.. Thanks a lot! I read on a guide that I had to ssh to create new repos. But I might have misread it. :)

But thanks again! :)

Comment: @MortenHagh and make sure to upgrade to gitolite V3 (no more `gl-xxx` commands) Support will be easier with an up-to-date version of Gitolite. See http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html and http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/install.html#migr

Comment: Thanks :) I will do that! :)

Just one more question! I am working on my projects in /var/www/
Can I add the projects to the repositories from there, or do each project have to be put into the same folder as gitolite-admin ?

Comment: Gitolite will store those new repos in its `repositories` directory, alongside the `gitolite-admin` repo. That doesn't prevent you to clone said new repos anywhere you want (provided you clone them through gitolite: `git clone git@server:reponame`). See http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/user.html