# Can't push files to git repo through Assembla by using Titanium Studio

Tags: git, assembla

everyone.

I created a git repo on Assembla, then imported it to Titanium Studio, then I copied the files into the folder, but it didn't let me push it. It says:

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@git.assembla.com:#######.git'
```

Anyone knows what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

The first push might require a `git push origin master` (as [explained here](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/git-tip-git-push-no-refs-in-common-and-none-specified/)).

In an IDE (like [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/platform/titanium-studio/)), this could be similar to this [bug report](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3557):

> The issue here is that our command just does a "`git push`" which pushes up branches that have remotes and tracking set up.
>   If you need to explicitly push the current branch to a named remote, use the "**`Team > Push to Remote`**" git command.
>   So if you're on '`master`', that will prompt you for the remote and then do "`git push master <remote>`".

Comment: It does require this since your local branch has no remote its tracking

Comment: @Michael I agree, after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506832/git-push-origin-masterrefs-heads-master-what-does-this-do/7506906#7506906 And the default push policy will make that more apparent: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586687/what-is-the-result-of-git-push-origin/9749477#9749477